# How to get output parameter values of a SQLCLR stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, sqlclr, output-parameter

I created a SQL Server database project (VS2017) and I added a SQLCLR C# stored procedure. It's declared like this:

```
public static void RequestServiceToEncryptPassword(byte[] param1, out int param2, out byte[] param3)
```

I also have a Windows Forms application that connects to the database and I try to execute this procedure like this:

```
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(procName, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", param1).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", int).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", byte[]).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
```

There's a problem with declared data type though. What is the correct way of declaring data types for SQLCLR stored procedures or getting its output parameter values?

Comment: You can declare an ouput param seperate and then add it to the collection. Then after an execute etc. check it's value. Otherwise you need to get the param by index and then check it's value. On another note, don't use `AddWithValue`, use `Add` and specify the data type; `AddWithValue` has to infer the data type and it may not be what you need. Also you are asking multiple questions, please try and stick to one and other's can be asked in another post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rather than using .NET types for input/output parameter types of SQLCLR objects, use the `Sql*` types, such as `SqlString`, `SqlInt32`, etc. All of them have a `Value` property that returns the expected .NET type. For example, `SqlString.Value` returns a `string`, `SqlInt32.Value` returns an `int`, and so on.
2. If the input can ever be `NULL`, you can test for that by checking the `IsNull` boolean property that all of the `Sql*` types have.
3. The appropriate replacement type for a `byte[]` is `SqlBytes`. And `SqlBytes.Value` will return a `byte[]`.
4. Even if not necessary, is probably best to decorate the method destined to be the SQLCLR stored procedure with: `[SqlProcedure()]`.
5. Putting the recommendations noted above together, we get:

   ```cs
   [SqlProcedure()]
   public static void  RequestServiceToEncryptPassword(SqlBytes param1,
        out SqlInt32 param2, out SqlBytes param3)
   {
     if(!param1.IsNull)
     {
        param2 = doSomethingWithByteArray(param1.Value);
     }

     ... more ....
   }
   ```
6. For the parameters, it is best to *not* use `AddWithValue` (as mentioned by Çöđěxěŕ in a comment on the question) as it can sometimes have problems, especially with variable length types (i.e. strings and binaries such as `VARCHAR`, `VARBINARY`, etc).
7. For the parameters, I prefer to create each parameter as an object, which makes it easy to interact with (and more readable for more maintainable code):

   ```cs
   paramParam1 = new SqlParameter("param1", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 500);
   // paramParam1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; // Input is default / assumed
   paramParam1.Value = param1;
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramParam1);

   paramParam2 = new SqlParameter("param2", SqlDbType.Int);
   paramParam2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
   paramParam2.Value = intVariable;
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramParam2);
   ```

   Please note that the optional size parameter of the `SqlParameter` constructor (i.e. the `500` for `param1`):

   1. should *always* be set for variable length types
   2. can be set to `SqlMetaData.Max` (which simply returns `-1`) for the `MAX` types
   3. should match the length declared for its associated paramter in the stored procedure (or user-defined function), which yes, also needs to have an explicitly declared length (you don't want to rely on the default as it's not the same value in all contexts)
8. After executing the `SqlCommand`, and output parameters will have their values set, and those can be accessed by reading their `Value` property. This value will likely need to be casted into a .NET type:

   ```cs
   int returnVal = (int)paramParam2.Value;
   ```
9. If it's possible for an output parameter to be set to `NULL`, then you need to check for `DbNull.Value` before casting it to the appropriate type.

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/?ref=so_58878220)